# What does “-t” in “Bucht” mean?

Tags: etymology

Wiktionary says, that "-t" in "Bucht" is a [variant of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-t#Etymology_3) Proto-Germanic "*-þiz" suffix (in other words Bucht = Bug + t) but I think, that "-t" in "Bucht" is a Proto-Germanic [past participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-t#Etymology_1) ending of "biegen". Is my hypothesis reasonable?

Comment: The same site also tells you the etymology of Bucht: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bucht

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer:

### Yes, you are right

---

long answer:

[English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bucht#Etymology) tells you about the German word *Bucht:*

> Via German Low German from Middle Low German *bucht,* from Old Saxon *buht*, from Proto-Germanic **buhtiz.* Cognate with Dutch *bocht.*

[German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bucht) says:

> von niederdeutsch *bucht* „Biegung, Krümmung“, „landeinwärts gebogene Strandlinie“, belegt seit dem 17. Jahrhundert. Das Wort gehört zur Wortfamilie *biegen*

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bucht) (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) says:

> **Bucht** f. ‘bogenförmig ins Land hineinragender Teil eines Meeres oder Binnengewässers’, auch ‘Haus-, Zimmerwinkel, Nische, Verschlag, kleiner Stall für Haustiere’. Mnd. *bucht* ‘Biegung, Krümmung, eingefriedeter Raum, Pferch, Stall’, aengl. *byht* ‘Winkel, Wohnstätte’, engl. *bight* ‘Bucht’, nl. *bocht* ‘Biegung, Bucht’, anord. *-bōt* in Zusammensetzungen für ‘Kniekehle’ (*knēsbōt*) und ‘Ellenbeuge’ (*ǫl(n) bogabōt*) sind ti-Abstrakta (germ. **buhti-*) zu den germ. Entsprechungen von nhd. ↗*biegen* (s. d.). Nd. *Bucht* wird in der auch im Nl. und Engl. vertretenen Bedeutung ‘Meerbusen’ im 17. Jh. ins Hd. übernommen; in der Bedeutung ‘Verschlag, Nische’ bleibt es auf das nordd. und md. Sprachgebiet beschränkt. In der Umgangssprache steht *Bucht* (auch *Buchte*) für ‘Bett’ nach der als Schlafstätte (ursprünglich Strohschütte) genutzten Zimmernische. **einbuchten** Vb. ‘bogenförmig einschneiden’, meist Part. Prät. *eingebuchtet* (Anfang 19. Jh.); umgangssprachlich (in einen abgeschlossenen Raum) ‘einsperren’ (19. Jh.).

And *"DUDEN - Das Herkunftswörterbuch"* (printed in 2001) says:

> **Bucht:** Das im 17. Jh. aus dem Niederd. in die hochd. Schriftsprache übernommene Wort geht zurück auf mnd. *bucht* »Biegung, Krümmung«, vgl. niederl. *bocht* »Biegung, Krümmung, Bucht«, engl. *bight* »Bucht«, aisl. *bōt* »Bucht, kleiner Meerbusen«. Das Substantiv ist eine Bildung zu dem unter ↑biegen behandelten Verb. Mnd. *bucht,* mniederl. *bocht* bedeutet auch »Einfreidung (Pferch, Verschlag) für Tiere» (noch nordd. in ›Schweine-, Kälberbucht‹), wobei wohl der Begriff »Winkel« zugrunde liegt. - Abl: **ausbuchten** »bogenförmig ausschneidern« (19. Jh.), dazu **Ausbuchtung, einbuchten** (19. Jh., wie ausbuchten, ugs. auch für »einsperren«, zu ›Bucht‹ »Verschlag«).

Also interesting: [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bucht)

> **bight (n.)**
>   Old English byht "bend, angle, corner," from Proto-Germanic *buhtiz (source also of Middle Low German bucht, German Bucht, Dutch bocht, Danish bught "bight, bay"), from PIE root *bheug- "to bend," with derivatives referring to bent, pliable, or curved objects. Sense of "long, narrow indentation on a coastline" is from late 15c.

**summary**

The German noun *Bucht* and the English noun *bight* both mean the same (i.e. *bay, bayou*), and both derive from the Proto-Germanic noun **buhtiz.*

So, you are right, the suffix *-t* is comming from *-tiz* (in Protogermanic letters: *-þiz.*

And, yes, it derives from the past paticiple of Proto-Indo-European verb **bheug* which is not only the root for German *beugen* (weak verb, PP: gebeug**t**, ending is *-t*) but also for *biegen* (strong verb, PP: gebog**en**, ending is *-en*), which are synonyms and both translate to English *to bend, to bow.*

Comment: The last and second to last paragraph directly contradict each other: *-ti* is distinct from *-to* (see Brugmann's *Nominale Stammbildungslehre* [§ 127](https://archive.org/details/nominalestammbi02kluggoog/page/n78), [§ 221](https://archive.org/details/nominalestammbi02kluggoog/page/n118)).

Comment: None of the sources you quoted support the hypothesis that *Bucht* is derived from a past participle. In fact, the last quote confirms the competing hypothesis.

Comment: Kluge, not Brugmann.

Comment: *Flucht*, *fliehen, fliegen* vs *Bucht, biegen* (Norddeutsch. *biehen* ~ *biejen)

Comment: *Wucht, wiegen, Gewicht, wagen, Wagen, Waage, wehen, Woge, weigern* [*Welle machen*? lol!] point to a diverse paradigm and thus old age. Given phonetic uncertainty I'd also compare a velar or uvular to a dry [ʀ], sometimes transcribed *gh*. Thus cp. e.g. *Geburt*, something very past participle like.

Comment: @vectory And with nasal infixes and/or _s_-prefix, we also get _Wange_, _Schwinge_, _schwach_, etc. Also, you missed _weich_, _wach_, _Weiher_, _Weg_, _Wuchs_, _Wechte_, _Wicht_, _Wucher_, _vegan_, _Wachs_, _Vagina_, _Wiegand_, _Waggon_, _Vigil_ and _au wei(h?)a_. This must be an old pattern indeed.

Comment: Why do you believe that the _ti_ abstractum derives from a past participle? At least the [Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ti-Abstraktum) doesn't give any reason to assume that would be the case.

Comment: @sgf *au wei(h)a*, is pretty good, gotta give you that; *Weh, weh-leidig, oh weh* may be that root, and does fit to *schwer*, and, errm, maybe *weary*. I do understand you were being sarcastic, though.

Comment: @vectory Heh, I _was_ pretty proud of that one. My point is this: While finding etymological patterns is a fun hobby, and one that I like, it seems that you do it in an awful lot of comments on questions or answers where it just isn't all that relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds quite unlikely, because "biegen" is a strong verb, so the past participle ends with -en ("gebogen" in German, "bogen" in Old English). So it would be hard to explain the weak past participle ending -t.

Comment: Where did you find it ("bogen" in Old English)?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/bow

Comment: Das starke Verb *biegen - gebogen* und das schwache Verb *beugen -gebeugt* sind nicht nur Synonyme, sondern haben auch dieselbe etymologische Wurzel, nämlich das Protoindogermanische Verb _*bheug._ Zu argumentieren, dass im modernen Deutsch ein Verb stark oder schwach ist, ist unsinnig, wenn es darum geht, ob sein Vorläufer auc schwach oder stark war. Da liegen fast 2000 Jahre dazwischen, und da kann sich einiges ändern.

Comment: @HubertSchönast, ist es das, oder könnte das vielleicht andeuten, dass ein wie auch immer gearteter Unterschied schon in Indogermanisch bestand, vielleicht nur in Erweiterung des Paradigmas? Dafür ist \*bhewH "to swell, grow; to become" etc sicherlich erwähnenswert. So hat *beugen* etwas signifikant negatives oder zumindest passives an sich (i.e. *su-bjugated*, I mean *sub-jugated* "unterjocht").

Comment: @vectory "subjugate" comes from Latin "iugum" (yoke), which is derived from some PIE root *yewg, not from *bhewH.

Comment: @Uwe *Bügel* very well fits the sense of *yoke*. Et voila. Thx for nagging.

Answer (score 1):

If your premisses is reasonable to assume, then it is also reasonable to assume--perhaps to the extend that the grammar allows it--to find the proposed connection reflected in PIE in a way that does not leave your assumption stand contradicted.

*-t is found in various instrumental morphemes [I mean, right?]. So our intuition does not count for much. As the equivalent [question ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502687/what-does-t-in-bight-mean) shows, the suffix PGem *-tiz was reconstructed as evidence of PIE *-ti-s, -s marking for [persona, number?], *ti- simply explained as *action-to-noun* forming suffix [although it's not said whether the compound was a PGem innovation as it seems]. This, I believe, is reflected in the short vowel *Bucht*, where verb forms would usually be long, cp. *Sucht* (~*Seuche*), *such-t* (~*Suche*).